# Can I freeze a form element with radio button?

Tags: ms-access

I'd like to freeze/lock my form element, when my radio button checked.

Is it solve with one database row? Should I use VBA scripting to do this?

[image: freeze form element]

Comment: Does 'freeze' mean to disable? Can use VBA or Conditional Formatting. You already asked this question and it was closed. You have not improved the question.

Answer (score 1):

A radio button is not for checking; that's what a *CheckBox* is for.

So, use a CheckBox and this code in the *AfterUpdate* event of this:

```vb
Private Sub YourCheckBox_AfterUpdate()

    Dim Frozen As Boolean

    Frozen = Nz(Me!YourCheckBox.Value)

    Me!YourTextBox.Locked = Frozen
    Me!YourTextBox.Enabled = Not Frozen

End Sub
```